# mongoc_init undefined reference

Tags: c, mongodb, makefile

I am trying to use the mongo C driver in a Trivia server program I am making to use it to track login information scores etc.

It took me a decent amount of time to figure out how to compile the stuff in a makefile but I was able to include mongoc.h so things like mongoc_client work fine. As soon as I try to actually use a function though, such as mongoc_init I get

```
> undefined reference to `mongoc_init'
```

I feel like things should be linked though since the mongoc.h include all other header files and it looks like it is linking properly. Here is my makefile - I'm not sure what to do or even what information to provide to solve this issue.

```
client:
    make -f makefile.client

server:
    make -f makefile.server

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o tserve core tclient core *.tar *.zip *.gzip *.bzip *.gz
```

^ Makefile

```
C = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lpthread
INFO = -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0

all: tserve

csapp.o: csapp.c csapp.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c csapp.c

tserve.o: tserve.c readq.h csapp.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c tserve.c $(INFO)

readq.o: readq.c readq.h csapp.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c readq.c

tserve: tserve.o readq.o csapp.o
```

^ makefile.server

```
C = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

all: tclient

csapp.o: csapp.c csapp.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c csapp.c

tclient.o: tclient.c csapp.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c tclient.c

tclient: tclient.o csapp.o
```

^ makefile.client

If it is worth noting - the system is question had the driver installed using the following code

```
system("wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.0.2/mongo-c-driver-1.0.2.tar.gz");
system("tar -xzf mongo-c-driver-1.0.2.tar.gz");
system("rm mongo-c-driver-1.0.2.tar.gz");
if (chdir("mongo-c-driver-1.0.2"))
    perror("error:");
system("./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64");
system("make");
system("sudo make install");
```

the code is also at https://www.github.com/decix/TriviaServer

Answer (score 0):

You only use the `INFO` variable, which contains `-lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0` (which is what you need), to build `tserve.o`. In this build step, the linker is not involved, so the `-l` options are not evaluated and don't do anything. Instead, you need to specify them when you build `tserve`.

You could solve this by supplying a recipe for `tserve` that does this, such as

```
tserve: tserve.o readq.o csapp.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(INFO) -o $@ $+
```

...but it would be better, in my opinion, to split `INFO` and put the parts into the variables that the predefined rules use for the relevant purposes. Then your whole Makefile could be replaced with

```
# C compiler
CC       = gcc
# C compiler flags
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall
# C preprocessor flags
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -pthread
# Linker flags
LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/local/lib -pthread
# Libraries
LDLIBS   = -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0

all: tserve

csapp.o: csapp.c csapp.h
tserve.o: tserve.c readq.h csapp.h
readq.o: readq.c readq.h csapp.h

tserve: tserve.o readq.o csapp.o
```

The `.o` files will then be built through implicit rules that generate them from corresponding `.c` files and use `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`, saving you the trouble of specifying the recipes explicitly -- the rules only exist to track dependencies -- and the linking step uses an implicit rule that uses `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`. Note that I supplied `-pthread` in both `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` because it is relevant for both the preprocessor and the linker.

For further information, see the bit about [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) in the GNU make manual, and speaking of dependency tracking, you may find [this article](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) about automating it enlightening.

Comment: so I got a few errors for the first recipe, cc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files, and then when I tried to use the second makefile I got a long stream of errors, I am not sure what to do with.

Comment: The first recipe does not contain `-c` or `-S`. Are there parts of your original makefile that you haven't posted that could be relevant for this? It should not result in a compiler call that passes either of those to `cc`. (By the way, that it uses `cc` instead of `gcc` is due to a typo in the first line of your makefile, where it says `C` instead of `CC`. This may not be a problem, though; if you're on a Linux system, `cc` is probably just an alias for `gcc`).

Comment: it is a linux system, but i will definitely fix that. i just added all the makefile info since it is a 3 part ordeal, as well as a link to source code - maybe that might help you understand where the issues are coming from

Comment: The libraries you're using are not packaged for my distro, so I cannot see if the code should link against them properly, but the makefile I gave you does the right things (I tested this with an empty tserve.c). I do not get an error about `-c` or `-S` being passed to `cc` along with `-o`, nor do I see how it could happen. Did you replace `makefile.server` with what I gave you?

Comment: yeah so the makefile is now at https://github.com/decix/TriviaServer/blob/master/makefile.server but i get an absurd amount of errors with this. The server is CentOS, is there perhaps missing libraries or something that would be causing these errors? http://i61.tinypic.com/4g0wfp.png that is the errors, I don't know how helpful that is.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I forgot the `-I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0` in `CPPFLAGS`. Let me just edit that in. (the bit that tipped me off is the "missing header file bson.h" at the top)

Comment: it works! thank you very much! i would upvote you but I actually am not even able to yet. thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

```
the following file is expected to be named Makefile.mak


# note: with very minor changes this should work for most C projects
#       irregardless of the OS being used

SHELL := /bin/sh

.PHONY: all clean

#
# macro for all *.c files
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


CC       := /usr/bin/gcc
MAKE     := /usr/bin/make


name := tserve

CFLAGS := -c -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors
#CPPFLAGS += =MD

# when #(DEBUG) is used in the compile/link steps,
# them max info for the gdb debugger is generated
DEBUG   := -ggdb3
LDFLAGS := -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib

LIBS :=  -lpthread -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0

INC := -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0
name := tserve

all: $(name)


#
# link the .o files into the executable
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #

#
#create dependancy files
# -- inference rule
#
%.d: %.c Makefile.mak
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========

#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. $(INC)
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    #


clean:
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========


ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```